# What does CoGroupedRDD do?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Can anyone explain in simple terms what a CoGroupedRDD do? Below code does a join between two RDDs

```
val schema = "some_schema"
val RDD = {sc.cassandraTable[(String, String, Int, Int, Int, Int)](schema, "Event_table").select("column1" as "_1", "column2" as "_2", "column3" as "_3", "column4" as "_4", "column5" as "_5","column6" as "_6").keyBy[Tuple2[Int,Int]]("column5","column6")}
val RDD2 = {sc.cassandraTable[(Int,Int)](ks, "crew_table").select ("crewid_1" as "_1", "crewid_2" as "_2", "crewid_desc").keyBy[Tuple2[Int, Int]]("crewid_1", "crewid_2")}
val joinedRDD = RDD.leftOuterJoin(RDD2)
joinedRDD.take(10).foreach(println)
val RDD3 = {sc.cassandraTable[(Int,String)](ks, "Crew").select ("crewid_1" as "_1", "crewid_2" as "_2").keyBy[Tuple1[Int]]("crew_id")}
 val mjoin = joinedRDD.map { x => (x._1._1, x._2) }


val result = mjoin.join(RDD3)
result.toDebugString
```

```
    res19: String = 
(6) MapPartitionsRDD[27] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:66 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[26] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:66 []
 |  CoGroupedRDD[25] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:66 []
 +-(6) MapPartitionsRDD[21] at map at <console>:60 []
 |  |  MapPartitionsRDD[17] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:58 []
 |  |  MapPartitionsRDD[16] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:58 []
 |  |  CoGroupedRDD[15] at leftOuterJoin at <console>:58 []
 |  +-(6) CassandraTableScanRDD[2] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15 []
 |  +-(6) CassandraTableScanRDD[5] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15 []
 +-(6) CassandraTableScanRDD[11] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15 []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form `cogroup` has a following signature:

```scala
def cogroup[W](other: RDD[(K, W)]): RDD[(K, (Iterable[V], Iterable[W]))]
```

where "self" is `RDD[(K, V)]`. To put it simple it takes to RDDs of key-value pairs and groups values by key, keeping values for each source logically separated:

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "foo"), (1, "bar"), (2, "foobar")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)))
rdd1.cogroup(rdd2).collect.foreach(println)
```

```
(1,(CompactBuffer(foo, bar),CompactBuffer(1, 2)))
(2,(CompactBuffer(foobar),CompactBuffer()))
(3,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(3)))
```

This mechanism is used to implement `joins`. Once data is co-grouped you can flatten it

```scala
for { lv <- lss; rv <- rvs } yield (key, (lv, rv))
```

to finalize inner join. Outer join follow the same procedure with small adjustments for empty sequences.